# How to simulate BT and WiFi connection during UI automation test with fastlane?

Tags: bluetooth, automated-tests, ui-testing, fastlane, fastlane-snapshot

I am beginner of iOS testing and I really need help. Thank you in advance.
I've tried to implement a simple test with fastlane to create screenshots and evaluate if all needed elements exist (fastlane snapshot, I follow most common tutorials and up to now everything works fine). App which is tested needs a WiFi and Bluetooth connection to open some tabs. I have no idea how to manage it. When app is redirected to view where connection is checked and test wait (methods such as `sleep(30)` or `waitForExists(app.otherElements["snapshotReady"], waitSeconds: 60)` but nothing happens and app cannot be loaded to the next view (generally, when app works on device context is switched to the next view). 
I could not find any programatically method anywhere to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this to look for the `FASTLANE_SNAPSHOT` key in the `UserDefaults` that is inserted automatically by *snapshot*.

```
if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "FASTLANE_SNAPSHOT") {
    // runtime check that we are in snapshot mode
}
```

You can use logic like this to simulate any user interfaces that you may need.

More info can be found at - https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/snapshot/#launch-arguments